# Problems after Importing an android project from github into Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'm trying to tinker with this project and am having some issues importing it.

https://github.com/HoloAddict/FeedEx

I'm a beginner still, and have made a couple of test projects from scratch, but I think I'd learn a little faster by going through working code in a larger project. Just can't get rid of errors to even build the existing code. These are the steps I have taken:

- imported it in as a Git project (file - Import - Git - Projects from Git)
- gen folder error (does not exist or not source) - right clicked on gen, Buld path - Use as a source folder. This made that particular error go away
- all the src files were listed as src.net.fred... packages, so all the imports were errors. Right click - build path - configure build path - added Feedex/src in build path, got rid of those errors.
- have the R.java problem... tried many clean-build approaches, no luck. Also tried taking one from a clean project, creating package net.fred.feedex in gen, creating file R.java, and putting code in from a clean project, but no luck. It did make the import R go away, but of course left many errors where the res class references are broken, again because that R file is missing (I think).

So that's where I am. It seems like I have an R.java problem, but I may have messed up on one of the other steps. Either way, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you imported the project did you check the "Copy projects into workspace"?

If not import your project again and see if this problem still continues.

Comment: I don't see that option at all when I use the Import- git dialogs.  There's a "select wizard to use" after it pulls the files down. Options are "Import Existing Project," "Use the New Project Wizard," and "Import as general project". I have been using the "exisitng" option.

Comment: Ok! So I downloaded the zip and unzipped, did File - Import - Android - Existing code into workspace, and what do you know, no errors. So I'm assuming, with android projects, using the git URI is not best practice? Thanks for guiding me to the right answer.